# Google PageSpeed Insights: Why is this css file rendering blocking?

Tags: html, css, google-pagespeed

Hello Google PageSpeed Insights tells me that the following CSS file is rendering blocking:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

.woocommerce_de_scrollable_textarea {
    height: 150px !important;
    width: 98% !important;
    overflow: auto !important;
    border: 1px solid #DDD !important;
    background-color: whiteSmoke !important;
    padding: 8px !important;
    display: block !important;
    color: #000 !important;
}

.products .woocommerce-de_price_taxrate {
    display: block;
}

.woocommerce-de_price_taxrate {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.woocommerce-de_price_shipping_rate {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.widerruf {
    clear: both;
}

.wgm-second-checkout input.wgm-place-order {
    float: right;
}

.checkout_productdesc {
    font-size: smaller;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.form-row .terms {
    float: left;
}

.price-per-unit {
    display: block;
}

.woocommerce_de_versandkosten {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    display: block;
}

.product-tax {
    font-weight: normal;
}

.product-total .amount,
.product-subtotal .amount {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}

.product-total .product-tax {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.wgm-tax,
.wgm-tax .amount,
.product-total .product-tax .amount,
.product-subtotal .product-tax .amount {
    font-weight: normal !important;
}

.wgm-tax,
.product-total .product-tax,
.product-subtotal .product-tax {
    font-size: smaller;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.total .includes_tax,
.order-total .includes_tax {
    /*display: block;*/
}

.shipping_de.shipping_de_string {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.wgm-break {
    display:block;
}

.wgm-order-table-tr {
    text-align:left; border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.wgm-order-table-tr-cond {
    border-top-width: 4px;
}

.wgm-kleinunternehmerregelung {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    display: block;
}

.wgm-kur-notice {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.wgm-kur-notice-review {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.wgm-virtual-notice {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.wgm-digital-checkout-notice {
    color: #ff0000;
    display: block;
    font-size: smaller;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.wgm-digital-variation-notice {
    display: block;
    font-size: smaller;
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.wgm-digital-attribute-list {
    font-size: smaller;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.wgm-digital-attribute-list li {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.wgm-product-prerequisites-label {
    display: block;
    font-size: smaller;
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.wgm-product-prerequisites {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    padding: 10px;
}

.single-product .wgm-product-prerequisites {
    font-size: smaller;
}

.wgm-extra-costs-eu {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.wc-terms-and-conditions .required{
    display:none;
}
```

It is included in the page like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='woocommerce-de_frontend_styles-css'  href='https://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-german-market/css/frontend.css?ver=1.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I can not see why the css is rendering blocking, can you tell me? It is included in the  section, but there are other css files as well and those are not marked as "rendering blocking"...

Would be great if someone has a hint.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's an idea to grab a correct stylesheet and compare that one to this one. Could it be something different in the way of using `pixels` , `em`. or using the `!important` statement. Or the comment in the `.total .includes_tax,
.order-total .includes_tax {` selector?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-blocking-css